# Blurred Text in IE 11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

There is a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/examples/BlurredText/) about Blurred text. It works fine with Chrome, Firefox, but not Internet Explorer. It becomes a big block of blurry black shadow.

In Internet Explorer 11:

[image: IE 11]

In Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

CSS is as follow:

```
#slogan {
    color: #000;
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 45%;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#slogan span {
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
    color: transparent;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#slogan').lettering();
var text = $('#slogan'),
    numLetters = text.find("span").length;
text.find("span").css('textShadowBlur', 50);
var cnt = 1;
var timer_init;
function randomBlurize() {
    text.find("span:nth-child(" + cnt + ")")
        .animate({
          'textShadowBlur': 0,
          'textShadowColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+55) + ')'
        });
    if(cnt < numLetters) {
        cnt++;
        timer_init = setTimeout(randomBlurize, 200);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer_init);
    }
}
$('#slogan').fadeIn(100, function() {
    randomBlurize();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slogan">Design To Inspire</div>
```

Somehow jsFiddle cannot re-produce the problem, but I still make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/w8RJ8/). My question is: How to fix IE 11's issue?

---

**Update:**

[image]

Here is the [test link](http://raptor.hk/dev/ie9test.html) using the @dcc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer version 9 as far back as version 5.5 you could use the IE specific CSS filter and transition attributes to blur text or images, and do a number of other effects.

To create a blur effect on text you would use `filter:Blur(Direction=XX, Strength=XX)`.  The rule requires that the targeted element also be defined with a `height:` and `width:`.

```
p { filter:Blur(Direction=45, Strength=8);height:40;width:400;font-size:20pt;font-weight:bold; }
```

If you want to use these features in newer versions of IE you can force them to run in IE9 mode by setting the meta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

---

### Further

- [MSDN Article: Visual Filters and Transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN Article: Blur Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Partially correct. The blur filter can be done, but the output is not the same as the effects shown in other modern browsers. Also, it will sacrifice other IE11 features, such as full support of CSS3 (e.g. support of keyframes). See [CSS Support on IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#font_and_text). Last, the CSS above is invalid; `height` and `width` should have units (and never use `pt` in CSS) and you should not set dimension in `p` selector. See updated question for screenshot of tried effects.